# What target triplet tags should I use to compile gcc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

So I've been trying to compile the newest gcc version for about 20h now, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing the errors. I'm using MSYS2 msys on a custom windows 64bit computer for the following operations. The gcc compiler executables required to compile gcc came with the binary version 20.03 of Code::Blocks IDE.

Here's what I do:

objdir=c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64

srcdir=c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/source/gcc-11.2.0

```
cd objdir

export PATH=/path/to/gcc_compiler_executable:$PATH

make distclean

../../source/gcc-11.2.0/contrib/download_prerequisites

../../source/gcc11.2.0/configure --enable-bootstrap --disable-shared --prefix=objdir --enable-gold --host=x86_64-pc-mingw64 --target=x86_64-pc-mingw64
```

The last function outputs this:

```
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-mingw64
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... no
checking for libsanitizer support... no
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... no
checking for libphobos support... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-g++... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-c++... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gpp... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-aCC... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-CC... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-cxx... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-cc++... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-cl.exe... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-FCC... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-KCC... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-RCC... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-xlC_r... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-xlC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... yes
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gnatbind... no
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gnatmake... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... tail -c +17 $$f1 > tmp-foo1; tail -c +17 $$f2 > tmp-foo2; cmp tmp-foo1 tmp-foo2
configure: WARNING: trying to bootstrap a cross compiler
checking for objdir... .libs
configure: WARNING: using in-tree isl, disabling version check
The following languages will be built: c,c++,fortran,lto,objc
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     target-libgomp target-libitm target-libsanitizer target-libphobos target-libffi target-libgo gnattools gotools target-libada target-libhsail-rt target-zlib target-liboffloadmic
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG...
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for yacc... no
checking for bison... no
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... no
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for flex... no
checking for makeinfo... no
/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/source/gcc-11.2.0/missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ar... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-as... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-dlltool... no
checking for ld... (cached) C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ld... (cached) C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-lipo... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-nm... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ranlib... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-strip... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-windres... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-windmc... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-objcopy... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-objdump... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-otool... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-readelf... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-cc... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gcc... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-c++... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-g++... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-cxx... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gxx... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gcc... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gfortran... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gccgo... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-gdc... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ar... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-as... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-dlltool... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ld... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-lipo... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-nm... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-objcopy... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-objdump... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-otool... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-ranlib... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-readelf... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-strip... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-windres... no
checking for x86_64-pc-mingw64-windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... pre-installed
checking where to find the target as... pre-installed
checking where to find the target cc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target dlltool... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gcc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gfortran... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gccgo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gdc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target ld... pre-installed
checking where to find the target lipo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target nm... pre-installed
checking where to find the target objcopy... pre-installed
checking where to find the target objdump... pre-installed
checking where to find the target otool... pre-installed
checking where to find the target ranlib... pre-installed
checking where to find the target readelf... pre-installed
checking where to find the target strip... pre-installed
checking where to find the target windres... pre-installed
checking where to find the target windmc... pre-installed
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

After that, I run :

```
make bootstrap-lean
```

And there, I get an error. This is the part I have been struggling with.

Output (beginning is truncated):

```
../libtool: line 1740: x86_64-pc-mingw64-ar: command not found
make[5]: *** [Makefile:477: libmpn.la] Error 127
make[5]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64/gmp/mpn'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:954: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64/gmp'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:773: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64/gmp'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:5845: all-stage1-gmp] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27716: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:28144: bootstrap-lean] Error 2
```

This error appears in the part where the program is trying to compile the GMP files.

I've narrowed down the error to the fact that the --host tag is set in the configure command, but if I don't set that tag, it defaults to x86_64-pc-msys. It works fine for a while, but further down the line, I get a bunch of errors and warnings in the srcdir/libiberty/pex-unix.c file, complaining about unresolved references and the fact that the 'this' variable interferes with the C++ 'this' keyword'. The --target tag defaults to the same triplet (x86_64-pc-msys).

Here's the error I'm referring to (beginning truncated):

```
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_wait':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:256:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'wait'; did you mean 'cwait'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       cpid = wait (status);
              ^~~~
              cwait
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: At top level:
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:323:3: warning: initialization of 'pid_t (*)(struct pex_obj *, pid_t,  int *, struct pex_time *, int,  const char **, int *)' {aka 'long long int (*)(struct pex_obj *, long long int,  int *, struct pex_time *, int,  const char **, int *)'} from incompatible pointer type 'int (*)(struct pex_obj *, pid_t,  int *, struct pex_time *, int,  const char **, int *)' {aka 'int (*)(struct pex_obj *, long long int,  int *, struct pex_time *, int,  const char **, int *)'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   pex_unix_wait,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:323:3: note: (near initialization for 'funcs.wait')
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'save_and_install_fd':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:382:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fcntl'; did you mean 'fcvt'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   flags = fcntl (old_fd, F_GETFD);
           ^~~~~
           fcvt
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:382:26: error: 'F_GETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
   flags = fcntl (old_fd, F_GETFD);
                          ^~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:382:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:395:20: error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'S_IEXEC'?
       if ((flags & FD_CLOEXEC) == 0 && fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~
                    S_IEXEC
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:395:55: error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
       if ((flags & FD_CLOEXEC) == 0 && fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
                                                       ^~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:408:31: error: 'F_DUPFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
       new_fd = fcntl (old_fd, F_DUPFD, 3);
                               ^~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'restore_fd':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:442:19: error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'S_IEXEC'?
       if (flags & FD_CLOEXEC)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                   S_IEXEC
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:444:29: error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
       return fcntl (old_fd, F_SETFD, flags);
                             ^~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_unix_exec_child':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:526:42: warning: passing argument 3 of 'spawnvpe' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pid = spawnvpe (_P_NOWAITO, executable, (cc_cp)argv, (cc_cp)env);
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from ../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:40:
C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:193:67: note: expected 'char * const*' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   intptr_t __cdecl spawnvpe(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:526:55: warning: passing argument 4 of 'spawnvpe' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pid = spawnvpe (_P_NOWAITO, executable, (cc_cp)argv, (cc_cp)env);
                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from ../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:40:
C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:193:90: note: expected 'char * const*' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   intptr_t __cdecl spawnvpe(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:528:41: warning: passing argument 3 of 'spawnve' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pid = spawnve (_P_NOWAITO, executable, (cc_cp)argv, (cc_cp)env);
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from ../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:40:
C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:191:66: note: expected 'char * const*' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   intptr_t __cdecl spawnve(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:528:54: warning: passing argument 4 of 'spawnve' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  pid = spawnve (_P_NOWAITO, executable, (cc_cp)argv, (cc_cp)env);
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from ../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:40:
C:/Programming/Editors/CodeBlocks/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/process.h:191:89: note: expected 'char * const*' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   intptr_t __cdecl spawnve(int,const char *_Filename,char *const _ArgList[],char *const _Env[]) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_unix_wait':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:777:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill'; did you mean 'tell'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     kill (pid, SIGTERM);
     ^~~~
     tell
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_unix_pipe':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:795:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pipe'; did you mean '_pipe'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   return pipe (p);
          ^~~~
          _pipe
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_unix_fdopenw':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:811:18: error: 'F_SETFD' undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (fcntl (fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
                  ^~~~~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:811:27: error: 'FD_CLOEXEC' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'S_IEXEC'?
   if (fcntl (fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) < 0)
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
                           S_IEXEC
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c: In function 'pex_unix_cleanup':
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:822:27: warning: identifier 'this' conflicts with C++ keyword [-Wc++-compat]
       struct status_list *this;
                           ^~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:825:7: warning: identifier 'this' conflicts with C++ keyword [-Wc++-compat]
       this = (struct status_list *) obj->sysdep;
       ^~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:826:14: warning: identifier 'this' conflicts with C++ keyword [-Wc++-compat]
       next = this->next;
              ^~~~
../../../source/gcc-11.2.0/libiberty/pex-unix.c:827:13: warning: identifier 'this' conflicts with C++ keyword [-Wc++-compat]
       free (this);
             ^~~~
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1140: pex-unix.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64/libiberty'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:15776: all-stage1-libiberty] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:27004: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Programming/GNU/GCC/GCC_11.2.0/builds/gcc-x86_64'
make: *** [Makefile:27432: bootstrap-lean] Error 2
```

So my questions are:

1.What kind of target triplets should I specify for --host and --target ? I've tried `gcc -dumpmachine` which gives `x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Assigning these values to --host and --target just throws back to the first problem.

2.Is the build target triplet correct, knowing that the script is running in the msys bash window ?

3.If none of the above can solve this compilation error, what should I do ?

I apologies for the (probably) not very clear question, it's pretty late over here and I'm not experienced at all in the field. If you need anymore specification, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `configure` can _not_ find basic tools like `ar` with the `x86_64-pc-mingw64-` prefix. `configure` outputs: `checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys`. So, did you try: `--host=x86_64-pc-msys`? Or, just leave off `--host` and `--target` altogether.

Comment: If you want to (1) run your compiler on x86_64-pc-msys and produce output for x86_64-pc-mingw64, just specify host=x86_64-pc-msys build=x86_64-pc-msys target=x86_64-pc-mingw64. If you want to (2) run you compiler on x86_64-pc-mingw64 and produce output for x86_64-pc-mingw64, **I think** you need to build and install compiler (1) first, then build binutils with it, then build compiler (2). Or perhaps just build mingw64 binutils with whatever (outdated) mingw64 compiler you happen to have, or just download them from wherever.

Comment: From my very limited and quite old experience, if you want to build GCC for the PC you're running, just omit host and target. If you want to build for another system, read the documentation on cross-compiling and "canadian cross". At least for the latter there used to be a script, and you will need all build, host and target options.

Comment: Have you tried `--build=x86_64-w64-mingw32` (without host/target)?